# Retrieve Image from Realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Here I am Adding Firebase Image :
[image]

NeonFragment.kt

```
class NeonFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNeonBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: PhotosAdapter
    private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNeonBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        adapter = PhotosAdapter()

        binding.neonRecyler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.neonRecyler.adapter = adapter

        dbRef.root.child("Image").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val list = ArrayList<ModelClass>()

                for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                    val model = snap.getValue(ModelClass::class.java)
                    model?.let { list.add(it) }
                }

                adapter.UpdateData(list)
                Toast.makeText(context, "OnData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

PhotosAdapter.kt

```
class PhotosAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.DataHolder>() {
    private var list = ArrayList<ModelClass>()
    private lateinit var context: Context

    class DataHolder(private val binding: LayoutPhotosBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataHolder {
        context = parent.context
        val binding = LayoutPhotosBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return DataHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataHolder, position: Int) {
        val dataModel = list[position]
        Glide.with(context).load(dataModel.image).into(holder.binding.imgData)
    }

    fun UpdateData(list: ArrayList<ModelClass>) {
        this.list = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

ModelClass

```
package com.custom.wallpaper.ModelClass

class ModelClass {
    var image: String = ""

    constructor(image: String) {
        this.image = image
    }
}
```

Help me to solve this problem , I want to Get Data From Firebase Realtime to User App i am also adding firebase image to let you know how the data structure is been added in Firebase , i am completely to Firebase , I have added two apps to one Firebase Project , one app for admin that he can add images to firebase , and second app to User that then can access images

Comment: dbRef.root.child("Image").child("Neon")

Comment: dbRef.root.child("Image\Neon")

Comment: dbRef.root.child("Image/Neon")

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to get Images from Realtime Database to My RecylerView , but with this code my image is not coming from database

Comment: As I have Added my Realtime Database Image also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update following line

```
dbRef.root.child("Image").child("Neon").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val list = ArrayList<ModelClass>()

            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val model = snap.getValue(ModelClass::class.java)
                model?.let { list.add(it) }
            }

            adapter.UpdateData(list)
            Toast.makeText(context, "OnData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Update following line

```
dbRef.root.child("Image").child("Neon").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val list = ArrayList<ModelClass>()

            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val model = snap.getValue(ModelClass::class.java)
                model?.let { list.add(it) }
            }

            adapter.UpdateData(list)
            Toast.makeText(context, "OnData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```